# Libgdx postprocessing with modelbatch in chain: opengl setting breaks model faces rendering order

Tags: opengl, libgdx

I use libgdx library with opengl-gl20 graphics.
I've added some library into rendering chain and it seams this brokes some opengl setting.

Problems:

- model faces forgets about their depth in rendering scene;
- inner faces are rendered (when outer faces are expected to be rendered).

So my rendered scene looks like:

[image: order fkd up]
<sub>(source: [cs617131.vk.me](http://cs617131.vk.me/v617131319/1de37/fAvpVv3jsiA.jpg))</sub>

I have no sources for this library and I couldn't debug what is going on inside.

---

Update after solved:

I found official sources of that compiled strange jar. This library I tried to use is [libgdx-contribs postprocessing](https://github.com/manuelbua/libgdx-contribs/tree/master/postprocessing).
Solution comes at once when I start read api - constructor of the main processor should get parameter depth=true:
new PostProcessor(true/*enable depth!*/, false, true);

Сonclusion:
situation on image shows rendering with disabled depth_buffer.

Comment: I'm sure you can see what's going on with APItrace or similar debugging tools

Comment: If the library changes OpenGL states you will see them in CodeXL or Nsight. Both can display the call-history for a frame.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use together libgdx#ModelBatch and [libgdx-contribs postprocessing](https://github.com/manuelbua/libgdx-contribs/tree/master/postprocessing) library 
you need create main post-processor with parameter depth=true:
new PostProcessor(true/*enable depth!*/, false, true).